# How to get the binding path string of an Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

Most simple and full example here can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbenfj

We want a simple component that does 4 things based on binding path:

1. display the value in input
2. add the i18n
3. Security hide when user is not allowed to see the field
4. Code completion on model.us => model.user...

We want something like this:

```
<app-input [value]="model.user.name"></qcr-input>
```

Which in the background does:

```
<div class="form-group form-material floating" *permission="requiredAuthority">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="value" name="{{value}}"/>
  <label class="floating-label">{{label}}</label>
</div>
```

The *permission is a directive that does not render the component if the logged in user does not have that permission.

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public value: string;

  public label: string;

  public requiredReadAuthority: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    let path = // HOW TO GET model.user.name here to be able to do the rest generate requiredAuthority 'model.user.name__READ' AND ge the label for key 'model.user.name'?
    // path should be 'model.user.name' here.
    this.requiredReadAuthority = this.path + '__READ';
    this.label = this.someServiceToGeti18n(this.path);
  }
}
```

I think this can be done using Directives but there is not much info about that as it revolves around getting the actual string based on 'model.user.name' angular framework code in the directive.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What's your exact question ? What have you tried so far ? Could you provide a [mcve] repdoucing your issue ? Are you encountering any issue at all ?

Comment: `let path = this.value` ? Seriously, it's not clear at all, provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com with your goal

Comment: Thank you for your response. The exact question is the title of the question: How to get the binding path string of an Angular component? When you have the actual binding path (in the example 'model.user.name') you can perform additional framework things like auto get a label and auto add security based on that value. I have tried creating a @Directive and somehow get that value ('model.user.name') on the component <app-input [value]="model.user.name"></qcr-input> but I cannot find the value anywhere like on TemplateRef or ViewContainerRef.

Comment: Okay I'm going to give up until your provide a [mcve] (third time asking ...). If not, good luck with your issue !

Comment: Thanks for your response and time trichetriche. I updated the original question to make it more clear what is expected. I cannot easily create a simple example as this is a very large copy right project. I hope someone can tell me where the binding path is stored on some Angular framework class accessible in e.g.. a directive TemplateRef or ViewContainerRef. Like: angularComponent.getBindingPathAsString() that returns 'model.user.name' (AND NOT the actual name of the user like John. I really WANT the 'model.user.name' so I can performa additional framework stuff with it.

Comment: Thanks trichetriche for your time. I will see if I can create the required example for you.

Comment: Okay, got your question a little bit clearer : that doesn't exist. You'll have to provide the "variable path" manually.

Comment: Ok I created an example for you here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbenfj

Comment: @trichetriche thank you for your response. Yes manual set the path as string was the backup but you lose code completion in the process. I was hoping some framework class was available for this as this would save days/weeks of development time in large projects using i18n and security. I updated the question with the example you requested https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbenfj

Answer (score 0):

Following your comments, I have made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3bygbb?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) that can do what you want. the drawback is that you have to know which components are going to be used (in the example, `AppComponent` and `HelloComponent`) in order to inject them.

But this start should give you some content to work on. If you have any question, feel free to ask it !

Comment: Thanks for your time. That was more or less 'plan B' however developers lose code completion, code navigation and error checks in IDE. It would be great if there was an Angular Framework class to get the raw template values of a component. e.g.: AngularTemplateUtils.getRawAttrVallue(component : any, attrName: string) and return (in the example above) 'model.user.name'.